# Neo4j process a json file in batch

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher to read the json file and do some processing to create/merge nodes and relationship,

```
// Read the json file
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///test/test.json') YIELD value

// Read the json fields as variables
with value.globalcustid as v_globalcustid, value.member_node_properties as member_node_properties, value.relationships as relationships

// Update the member node demographic properties, if the member node does not exist, create it
MERGE (m:Member {globalcustid: v_globalcustid})
ON CREATE SET m.age_group=member_node_properties.age_group, m.gender=member_node_properties.gender, m.education=member_node_properties.education
ON MATCH SET m.age_group=member_node_properties.age_group, m.gender=member_node_properties.gender, m.education=member_node_properties.education

// Unwind the relationships array into multiple rows of relationship
with v_globalcustid, m, member_node_properties, relationships
UNWIND relationships as r

// Get the tag node and skip the null tag
with m, v_globalcustid, r, r.node.label as node_label, r.node.tag_id as tag_id
where tag_id is not null
CALL apoc.cypher.run(
    "MATCH (t:" + node_label + " {tag_id: '" + tag_id +"'}) RETURN t limit 1", 
    {}
) yield value as tag_node

// Merge the relationship of member node and tag node
with m, v_globalcustid, r, tag_node.t as tag_node
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(
  m, 
  r.relationship.label,
  {createdate: r.relationship.createdate, enddate: r.relationship.enddate, value: r.relationship.value},
  {},
  tag_node,
  {}
) YIELD rel

return *
```

The cypher was working fine with a small json file, then I found that when the json file is too large, it will have out of memory error, so I decided to put it in batch.

```
:auto

// Read the json file
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///test/test.json') YIELD value

// Read the json fields as variables
with value.globalcustid as v_globalcustid, value.member_node_properties as member_node_properties, value.relationships as relationships

call {
with v_globalcustid, member_node_properties, relationships

// Update the member node demographic properties, if the member node does not exist, create it
MERGE (m:Member {globalcustid: v_globalcustid})
ON CREATE SET m.age_group=member_node_properties.age_group, m.gender=member_node_properties.gender, m.education=member_node_properties.education
ON MATCH SET m.age_group=member_node_properties.age_group, m.gender=member_node_properties.gender, m.education=member_node_properties.education

// Unwind the relationships array into multiple rows of relationship
with v_globalcustid, m, member_node_properties, relationships
UNWIND relationships as r

// Get the tag node and skip the null tag
with m, v_globalcustid, r, r.node.label as node_label, r.node.tag_id as tag_id
where tag_id is not null
CALL apoc.cypher.run(
    "MATCH (t:" + node_label + " {tag_id: '" + tag_id +"'}) RETURN t limit 1", 
    {}
) yield value as tag_node

// Merge the relationship of member node and tag node
with m, v_globalcustid, r, tag_node.t as tag_node
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(
  m, 
  r.relationship.label,
  {createdate: r.relationship.createdate, enddate: r.relationship.enddate, value: r.relationship.value},
  {},
  tag_node,
  {}
) YIELD rel

return *
} in transactions of 10000 rows
```

But it looks like it does not work to call another procedure inside the call {} block?

```
Query cannot conclude with CALL together with YIELD (line 31, column 1 (offset: 1319))
"CALL apoc.merge.relationship("
 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second query should fail because the `RETURN *` is projecting out variables that have already been declared in the outer scope e.g. `v_globalcustid`.

To address your original problem, just return `null`:

```sql
CALL {
  // other stuff
  CALL apoc.merge.relationship(
    m, 
    r.relationship.label,
    { 
      createdate: r.relationship.createdate, 
      enddate: r.relationship.enddate, 
      value: r.relationship.value
    },
    {},
    tag_node,
    {}
  ) YIELD rel
  RETURN null AS discard
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 10000 ROWS
RETURN null
```

This is necessary because `CALL` subqueries have to conclude with either a `RETURN` or a write operation such as `CREATE`. Although `apoc.merge.relationship` does perform writes, Cypher treats it as a read operation that has to return a value.